# IE7 alpha filter cascading to all the other elements... how to stop it?

Tags: filter, internet-explorer-7, transparency, alpha

I have this page where my container have a background image using

```
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.76); 
*background-color:#fff; 
*opacity: 0.8; 
*filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
```

in Mozilla works ok; shows the translucent background and the elements inside completely opaque; but in IE7 the transparency inherits to all other elements. I've tried making a new container inside the container giving

```
*opacity:1, *alpha(opacity=100), *zoom:1, *filter:none
```

and stuff but nothing seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a semi-transparent background-image, it will work in every browser (except IE6...)

Comment: this won't work, IE7 has a bug for png backgrounds. check here: http://idea15.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/fixing-the-png-bug-in-ie7/

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because you are using the opacity and filter css tags, which will be inherited by child elements.

Try using the following:

```
.element{
   -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   -moz-opacity:0.8;
   -khtml-opacity:0.8;
   opacity:0.8;
}

.element *{
   -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   -moz-opacity:1.0;
   -khtml-opacity:1.0;
   opacity:1.0;
}
```

This should select all child elements and set their opacity to 100% and should work in all browsers

Comment: It won't work because the parent is already transparent, you can't "reset" the transparency of the children elements inheriting it. You would indeed need a "120%" alpha ;-)

Comment: ...so... I'm screwed? can't be!!

Comment: guys, I came up with a solution: just put the rgb color so mozilla recognize it, and a ie7 hack so explorer shows just a transparent png, like so: `code` background-color:rgba(234, 236, 235, 0.76);
 *background-image:url(images/wite70pc.png); `code`
this just did it...